# How to get right TextView position over Image for all screen types?

Tags: android, android-layout

There is an image with areas for text and several TextViews over it. I'm using layouts for different dpi(layout-mdpi, layout-hdpi, layout-xhdpi), but for different resolutions my TextViews still move out. Is there any way to achieve right TextViews positions for all screen resolution and dpi?
Using 'layout-hdpi-800x480' format gives right result, but I need to cover all screen types.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/faqImage1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/image_01" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/faqImage1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/faqImage1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/text1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/faqImage1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/text2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: see ImageView.getImageMatrix() and Matrix.mapPoints()

Comment: Isn't it better to use FrameLayout to place TextView over ImageView?

Answer (score 0):

I think that will help you their is "android:layout_alignParentRight" and "android:layout_alignParentLeft" tag available with relative layout child which help you to show text view right of screen

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/faqImage1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/image_default_logo"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:paddingLeft="30dp" 
             android:paddingTop="30dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/faqImage1"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:text="Text1"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingRight="30dp" 
             android:paddingBottom="30dp"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want something else then place a screen shot of your design what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: android:layout_alignParentRight and android:layout_alignParentLeft doesn't give correct result. Here is link to pic with scheme [link](http://dropmefiles.com/IXf1m).

Comment: Who said you android:layout_alignParentRight and android:layout_alignParentLeft doesn't give correct result.lets check the code with latest changes.And its better if you define in different dimens file under values folder, which wiil support you for different screen size.